# Two Accounts against Two OAuth2 Systems and AccountManager

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

The application we're working on authenticates against two OAuth2 providers so requiring 2 sets of username and password from the user.

Is it possible to create two Accounts in AccountManager?

Also, if it's possible, could another future app also access one of the two Accounts?